# Bitcoin Cash accidentally sent to Bitcoin segwit address

Tags: address, bitcoin-cash, cross-chain-recovery

Bitcoin Cash accidentally sent to Bitcoin segwit address starting with 3. Can I get them back?

Comment: @pebwindkraft there is a difference: recovering BTC sent to BCC address is trivial. Recovering BCC sent to **segwit** (P2SH) address is almost impossible :)

Comment: @amaclin SegWit outputs are anyonecanspend to non-SegWit nodes (which includes Bitcoin Cash), so recovering should be easy

Comment: @Pieter, there are no mining nodes with SCRIPT_VERIFY_CLEANSTACK cleared flag :)

Comment: @PieterWuille Is there a guide for that? Is it possible without the help of the miners?

Comment: @PieterWuille: Except that the miner could use the published inputscript to spend the coins to themselves?

Comment: @Lucas Guimarães, can you add more info about your mistake? Did you send your funds to p2pkh address (starts with '1') or to p2sh address (starts with '3') **Do not publish funds destination address if it starts with '3'**

Comment: @amaclin the destination address starts with 3

Comment: @amaclin since the address starts with 3, does that mean there is no way to recover the coins? were the coins lost or did they end up in someone else's wallet?

Comment: no. it does not mean it, but i've said that it can be either difficult or very difficult. if you do not trust me - ask  @PieterWuille - he said that it is easy. my email is alistermaclin@mail.ru - i think that it is better not to discuss here

Comment: Because of the comments above, I do not think this should be closed as a duplicate of that question, there is a lot more to this question than that one

Comment: @PieterWuille do you think you could try to help me rescue these BCC coins that are unspent in a segwit address where I mistakenly sent them?